# Looking up Google Cloud DNS records (nslookup) directly

Tags: google-cloud-dns

I'm in the process of testing GC DNS and have created zones and records. However, doing `nslookup` (windows/command line) times out when querying assigned Google NS directly:

```
> www.some_domain_A_record.com.
Server:  ns-cloud1.googledomains.com
Addresses:  2001:4860:4802:32::6e
          216.239.32.110

DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
DNS request timed out.
    timeout was 2 seconds.
*** Request to ns-cloud-e1.googledomains.com timed-out
```

Does anyone have any advice/input on this?

Notes:

- I am **only** using Cloud DNS for this project (no GCE/GAE/VM, etc.), essentially "just DNS". I'm looking to migrate from some existing DNS (only) provider to Google cloud DNS
- This means resources (A, CNAME, MX, etc.) aren't necessarily related to any GC hosted app or service (some could be - e.g. Google Apps/Work, etc.). In other words "typical" DNS zone/records.
- This is for an *existing/live* domain/zone
- I have not made any changes at the registrar level (I'm testing first) and querying the google ns assigned for the zone directly

> *To SO community: 
>
>   Completely understood that this isn't a programming question. Its just that this is the "Bronze" level support area for Google.*

---

### Update

Using Mac terminal actually **succeeds**

```
> server
Default server: ns-cloud1.googledomains.com
Address: 216.239.32.106#53
> gcloud-test.some_domain_I_have.com.
Server:     ns-cloud1.googledomains.com
Address:    216.239.32.106#53

gcloud-test.some_domain_I_have.com  canonical name = the_right_target.com.
Name:   the_right_target.com
Address: 1.2.3.4
```

Will dig some more, seems something to do with Windows `nslookup`..weird...it's not some firewall, I can `nslookup` some other domain using whatever specific (or public) name server.

---

### Update 2

Getting weirder - Windows (10 not that it should matter) on same Mac (vm/parallels) above works fine as well...

## Update 3

As of today 9-24-2015 it seems the odd behavior on Windows `nslookup` (*interactive mode*) when querying your assigned Google ns directly is resolved.

---

**Bottom line: All's good and running quite smoothly!** To the Google Cloud I go :)

On (**all***) **Windows** - it just seems that if you have/want to query your assigned Google NS *directly*, you have to do `nslookup` in non-interactive mode (aka "one liner") as shown below. You'll do this if you want to check/query resources *before* DNS propagation (after which, you don't really need to query your assigned NS directly).

Alternatively, you could `nslookup` interactive mode if you use the IP address of your assigned Google NS (sample also below).

****"all Windows"*** - meaning host/pc and OS. As above, Windows on Mac (VM/Parallels) is strangely unaffected by this weirdness - you can use `nslookup` interactive mode and query your ns directly just fine...
Mac/OSX terminal is fine/unaffacted

---

Partial answer, scoped to Windows:

To make it work,

- use `nslookup` in **non-interative** mode: *nslookup name-of-resource the-google-ns*
  e.g. `nslookup foo.com ns-cloud1.googledomains.com`
  or
- use the IP address of the google ns in **interactive** mode:

  ```
  c:\nslookup
  > server 216.239.32.106
  Default Server:  ns-cloud-a1.googledomains.com
  Address:  216.239.32.106

  > the_resource_to_lookup
  ```

As to "why", I'll defer to network folk - haven't worn that hat in years -*seems* something to do with PTR/reverse lookup, but that's just a guess...

Answer (score 2):

Looking at your inquiries, on your Windows you're using `ns-cloud-e1.googledomains.com` as the name server, however on your Mac you're using `ns-cloud1.googledomains.com` which is `ns-cloud-a1.googledomains.com`.

If both inquiries are for the same zone, then `time-out` on the first nslookup inquiry makes sense. Your workaround used a correct DNS server for the nslookup inquiry.

The solution is modifing your Windows DNS settings from `ns-cloud-e1.googledomains.com` to `ns-cloud-a1.googledomains.com` (same DNS settings of your Mac).

Using the Developers Console, under Cloud DNS you can verify what DNS servers your zone is associated to.

Comment: That was just a typo. I was using the correct ns assigned to my zone. In any case,after Registrar changes (after realizing it seems to just be a Windows only thing) and waiting for DNS propagation (global) - seems to have covered all that I can check by this time and all's good. It just seems I can't query the Google ns directly in windows nslookkup interactively. If I do it non-interactive mode (one line query), all's good too. Thank you!